# PHP best CAPTCHA choice

Tags: php, jquery, captcha

I develop a website registration form. I am just wondering which is the best CAPTCHA to embed into my code. One more criteria of choice will be how simple can I embed it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/captcha?sort=votes&pagesize=50

Comment: What's the matter with you? Why are you down voting this question?

Comment: I downvoted b/c you showed no research effort, and the question isn't useful. Both points supported by the fact that the question was closed as not a real question.. and it's been asked numerous times before with clearer criteria and goal.

Comment: You can try this: http://captchas.net/sample/php/ .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[reCAPTCHA](http://www.google.com/recaptcha) definitely. Reasons:

- Hard to break
- Google develops it
- Not just random strings but you help to digitalize books
- Easy to integrate.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Is it free to use it on my own website form?

Comment: At the link you can see how it looks like and googling `recaptcha tutorial php` will give you many tutorials on installing. And yes, it's free.

Comment: @paokg4 Did you read the site?

Comment: Ok thank you very much, I'll read it.

Comment: @axiomer reCaptcha challenge letters are very very difficult to read , And visitors are not like to read such a complicated string.